# Where is the HTTPD.CONF file?

Tags: raspbian, web-server, apache-httpd

I am attempting to stop people from being able to browse directories on my server.

I have a fully functioning public facing LAMP on my pi but when you type in a dir name or my ip address you can see the DIR info.

Here is a live example
http://anthonyrussell.info/postimages/

I was told to change this by editing the httpd.conf file but when I search for it, it doesn't exist.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On Debian (the operating system Raspbian is based on) and Raspbian the config file is `apache2.conf` (not `httpd.conf`) and it should be in `/etc/apache2`.

Answer (score -6):

On my Raspberry Pi (Debian), with Apache installed, there is no httpd.conf, there is ports.conf. And it is located in /etc/apache2/ports.conf.